# Can not access obj after call to $location.url

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two views, the first one calls function from the controller admin

`<a ng-click="updateAdmin(admin)">update</a>`

The controller code is

```
$scope.updateAdmin = function(admin){
    console.log(admin);//give result
    $scope.updateAdminValues = admin;
    $location.url ('/updateadmin');
    console.log(updateAdminValues);//give result        
}
```

The second view is:`{{ updateAdminValues._id }}`

The first view and second view have same controller

Comment: I'm not really sure what your problem is here, but your log statement should be: `console.log($scope.updateAdminValues)`.

Comment: you are right $scope.updateAdminValues

Comment: i cant access  $scope.updateAdminValues from the view

Comment: When your controller loads for second view, the value of updateAdminValues becomes undefined

Comment: @Vivz is right, if you're changing the location to a different URL, your routing will create a new instance of the controller that will not have the same `$scope`.

Comment: is there any solution to pass data from view to anther view or i must send the PK by the url then i send req to server ro get information of the admin

Comment: You can use angular service to share the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement setter and getter methods in a common service

**Factory**:

```
.factory('CommonService', function ($http, $state, Ls, md5, $filter) {
var info;
return {
    setData: function (data) {
         info  = data;
    },
    getData: function () {
        return info ;
    }
});
```

**Controller(First View)**:

```
$scope.updateAdmin = function(admin){
    console.log(admin);//give result
    $scope.updateAdminValues1 = admin;
    CommonService.setData($scope.updateAdminValues1);
    $location.url ('/updateadmin');
    console.log(updateAdminValues1);//give result        
}
```

**Controller(Second View)**:

```
$scope.updateAdminValues2 = CommonService.getData();
```

Comment: the problem is we have same controller

Comment: When your first view loads, $scope.updateAdminValues2 will be undefined because it has not been set. But after calling your update method, the service will set its value. And then for your second view when controller loads, you will get get the value from service scope.updateAdminValues2 = CommonService.getData();